# Why the confidence interval for proportion does not depend on the population size?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

The formula for a 95% confidence interval for proportion is

$\hat{p}\pm 1.96 \sqrt{p(1-p)}$

Suposing a sample of 200, calculating a proportion of 1.8%, the confidence interval is 1.67% - 1.93%.
But, what if the population size is about 1 billion? Is this correct?
I know that there is a finite population correction factor to small populations, but my thought is about big populations with very different sizes.

The formula can be used even to a a 1 million population also to a 1 billion population?

Comment: What if the proportion you want to estimate is the proportion of tosses of a certain biased coin come up heads? The population is what, all possible tosses? An infinite population? So how big a sample would you thunk would be needed?

Comment: If your intuition is that it should be costlier and more difficult to estimate a proportion in a population of a billion than in a population of ten thousand, you're right; but it's not because you need a bigger sample size, it's because it's harser to get a truly random sample of 200 from the bigger population.

Comment: You left out an important factor of $1/\sqrt n$ where $n$ is the sample size. Also, how do you get a proportion $1.8\%$ from a sample size of $200$?